# Convention about distinctness of the elements of a set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Sooo...if we write something as:
Let $$A=\{a,b,c\}$$, does it implicitly mean that a,b,c are distinct from each other? If the problem does not explictily state this?

And i've encountered a context like this:
Given the algebraic equation $x^3+mx^2+nx+p=0$ with roots a,b,c, 
find  p such that the multiplicative group generated by the set {a,b,c} is finite.
Here, the notation : set {a,b,c} implies that a,b,c are distinct, or not?
I would say ..not. But ho about that elementary school convention that in a set the elements do not repeat?

Comment: I guess you could say that the convention is that the set $\{a,b,c\}$ and the set $\{a,a,b,c\}$ are the same

Comment: There's no reason to assume that they must be distinct. In the case $a=b$, for instance, all that means is that $\{a,b,c\}=\{a,a,c\}=\{a,c\}$. The main thing we're doing writing the variables distinctly is allowing that the set *may* contain as many as three things.

Answer (score 1):

As you already indicate it is a matter of convention. It would be bad form to *knowingly* enumerate the same element multiple times, but when the elements have a general form (or when they are considered unknown) the usual understanding is as you say, namely, to permit identity among the enumerated elements.

Comment: I think it's an ambiguity that confuses students sometimes. For example, in a textbook for 5 grade in my country, there's the following trivial exercise: find the values of x such that we have  teh set {2,3,x} is included in the set {1,2,3,5}. At the answers it says :  x is 1 or 5, only.

Comment: Think back how often you have seen an author use the expression $i\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$ without making any exception for the case $n=1.$

Comment: The 5th grade exercise is questionable because its answer depends heavily on a not-so-stable convention.